# how to run sql file which contains set define off using ant

Tags: ant

I have this dbobject.file which in turn calls several dml,ddl and prcs.
I am trying to execute this file using ant but it requires only the sql statements,throws error for set define and spool.It is working using sqlplus but I want to run using ant,so calling this dbobject file should execute the dmls and ddls.

```
set define off
spool dbobjects.log
prompt calling D:\Pst1\Intel\tag\txt1.dml
@"D:\Pst1\Intel\tag\txt1.dml"
prompt calling D:\Pst\Intel\tag\txt2.dml
@"D:\Pst\Intel\tag\txt2.dml"
set define on
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of your question it sounds like you're trying to figure out how to convert an Oracle sqlplus script into a [SQL Ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html).

Both `spool` and `set` aren't SQL commands, they don't affect the server, instead they change how sqlplus operates locally. So in the context of Ant they wouldn't mean anything. If you're printing results in your script you can use the `output=` attribute to do something roughly similar.

If you were converting your sqlplus script to Ant I'd expect it to look something like this:

```
<sql driver="org.database.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:database-url" userid="sa" password="pass"
    src="txt1.dml"
    output="dbobjects.log" />
<sql driver="org.database.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:database-url" userid="sa" password="pass"
    src="txt2.dml"
    output="dbobjects.log"
    append="true" />
```

This would execute txt1.dml and txt2.dml as a set of SQL files against your database and would save any result sets generated into dbobjects.log.

This may not work in all cases especially if you're relying on anything sqlplus provides like report formatting or nested imports. In that case you'd need to rewrite your source files to only contain SQL.